# Rounded button color picker in android

Tags: android, color-picker

I want to have a rounded button color picker for my application like below.

What I have tried is this. Creating so many rounded buttons with different background colors. It seems bit inefficient. Clicking on the button will select the color. Is there a better way to do this ?

```
//rounded.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="35dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="35dp"
        android:topRightRadius="35dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="35dp"/>
</shape>

//In Layout
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="Button" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you use [**`FloatingActionButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton)

> A floating action button (FAB) is a circular button that triggers the primary action in your app's UI
>
> Floating action buttons are used for a special type of promoted action. They are distinguished by a circled icon floating above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing, launching, and the transferring anchor point.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

**EDIT**

For color picker you can use following libarry

- https://github.com/iluxonchik/Android-Color-Picker
- https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker

Comment: Pls read the question. I don't need floating button. I need color picker. I have seen some apps using color pickers as seen in the attached picture.

Comment: @YesudassMoses you can use color picker lib for that

Comment: Thank you @Nilesh.

Comment: @YesudassMoses happy to help u